# PHP "delay" a piece of code while the rest runs

Tags: php

I'm a java dev and I'm working on a multi-language project which has a few bugs in PHP code.

I have this PHP page that I need to be able to visualize and use. After some time I need to run a few lines of code (lets say 1 our, in reality the time is variable).

Those few lines would send a script alert, redirect to homepage and save records in the db. An operation that could not be done on page initialization.

I need the redirect only on one page, the rest of the site will be fully accessible at any time

I tried with `sleep()`, but it stopped the whole page from executing, which is the opposite of what I need. I also tried a script with `SessionTimeout()`, but it doesn't work unless the user stays afk for 1 hour.

What's the easiest way to do such thing?

UPTDATE:

I found a way to force redirect at the right time.

```
header('Refresh' . $time . ';$urlToBeRedirectedTo');
```

it might not be the most elegant solution, but it works

i still need to figure out how to run separately the alert script and the method to save records in db

Comment: So, you don't so much need to delay the PHP code, as have a bit of code that you need to run separately, some time later?

Comment: I'd separate it from the page.  Have some background process (scheduled or in some way continuous) which monitors data for "tasks" to be performed.  The page simply writes to that data.

Comment: @GregSchmidt exactly, you explained the problem better than i did

Comment: Making a redirect an hour later in PHP makes no sense. This needs to be done client side.

Comment: I agree with @gre_gor. There is no guarantee the user will still be on that page after an hour. It’s probably better to have your delayed code set a flag in the database, and check for that on the page that needs to redirect. You could poll it as well, just in case the page actually still is open after that hour.

Comment: the code will automatically save records if the user leaves the page, somehow it doesn't if i force redirect

Answer (score -2):

CRON task is usually suited for this senario. You can do it with [your command line](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux) or with a UI, eg.: with [CPannel](https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-configure-a-cron-job/) or with [nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/427380/how-to-run-a-daily-cron-job-nginx)